Evaluating $\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}\left(\ln(x^4+4)-\ln(x^2+4)\right)\mathrm{d}x$
The problem is to calcultate
$$\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}\left(\ln(x^4+4)-\ln(x^2+4)\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
I have tried the usual substitution method. Let $y=\frac{2}{x}$, then I get
$$\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}\ln\frac{x^4+4}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x-(\ln 2)^2,$$
but it doesn't work.
I guess the result is $\frac{(\ln2)^2}{2}$.

I've proposed this integral to Crux Mathematicorum a few years ago - it appeared as problem 4544 and an approach can be found here (page 520).

More generally,
$$\int_1^a\frac{\ln(x^4+a^2)-\ln(x^2+a^2)}xdx$$
$$=\frac12\int_1^{a^2}\frac{\ln(y^2+a^2)}ydy-\int_1^a\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}xdx$$
$$=\frac12\left(\int_a^{a^2}\frac{\ln(y^2+a^2)}ydy-\int_1^a\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}xdx\right)$$
$$=\frac12\left(\int_1^a\frac{\ln((a^2/t)^2+a^2)}tdt-\int_1^a\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}xdx\right)$$
$$=\frac12\int_1^a\frac{\ln(a^2/t^2)}tdt=\frac{\ln^2a}2$$

+1 for an answer that doesn't unnecessarily pass through dilogarithms.

Basically by definition the integral is
$1/2 \operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2/4) - 1/4 \operatorname{Li}_2(-x^4/4)$
where the dilogarithm function is used.
Now the dilogarithm of -1 is known to be $-\pi^2 /12$. Hence we get
$-π^2/24 - (\operatorname{Li}_2(-4))/4 -(\operatorname{Li}_2(-1/4))/4$
which can be evaluated using the formula
$\operatorname{Li}_2(z) +\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = - \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{(\ln(-z))^2}{2}.$
Final result: $\ln^2(4)/8=\ln^2(2)/2$

We have
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac12Li_2\left(\frac{-x^2}4\right)
&=\frac{ \frac12 Li_1 \left(\frac{-x^2}4\right)\cdot\frac{-2x}4}{ \frac {-x^2}4}\\
&=\frac{ -\ln(1+\frac{x^2}4)}{x }\\
&=\frac{\ln 4 -\ln(x^2+4)}{x}.\end{align}$$
In the same way,
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac14Li_2\left(\frac{-x^4}4\right)
&=\frac{ \frac14 Li_1 \left(\frac{-x^4}4\right)\cdot(-x^3)}{ \frac {-x^4}4}\\
&=\frac{ -\ln(1+\frac{x^4}4)}{x }\\
&=\frac{\ln 4 -\ln(x^4+4)}{x}.\end{align}$$
Hence $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac12Li_2\left(\frac{-x^2}4\right) - \frac14Li_2\left(\frac{-x^4}4\right)\right) = \frac{\ln(x^4+4)+\ln(x^2+4)}{x}.$$
So the integral in question is equal to $$\begin{align}&\left.\left(\frac12Li_2\left(\frac{-x^2}4\right) - \frac14Li_2\left(\frac{-x^4}4\right)\right) \right|_1^2\\&=
\frac12Li_2 \left(-1 \right)-\frac14Li_2 \left(-4 \right)-\frac12Li_2 \left(-\frac14 \right)+ \frac14Li_2 \left(-\frac14 \right)\\
&=
\frac12Li_2 \left(-1 \right)-\frac14Li_2 \left(-4 \right)-\frac14Li_2 \left(-\frac14 \right)\\
&= \frac12Li_2 \left(-1 \right)-\frac14 \left(Li_2 \left(-4 \right) +Li_2 \left(-\frac14 \right) \right)\\
&= \frac12\cdot\frac{-\pi^2}{12}-\frac14\left(\left(\frac{-\pi^2}6 \right)-\frac{ln^24}2\right)\\
&=\frac{\ln^22}2
.\end{align}$$
